# Setting css properties on HTML email

Tags: html, css

I'm sending an automatic html email from my website. In my email I set some text to red color and the font to a certain font type. When I view the html email from yahoo mail, The red color is applied, but the font is not applied. Why is it?

Also, when I try to view the html source code of the yahoo mail web page, I cannot find my html email content on this html source code. why is it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

```
<h2 style="color: #CC0000; text-align: center;">
    Welcome to the Dave&#39;s Photo Album</h2>
<p>
    Hi <%UserName%>,</p>
<p>
    Thanks for registering. Here is your new user name and password:</p>
<p>
    User Name: <%UserName%>
</p>
<p>
    Password: <%Password%>
</p>
<p>
    Enjoy!
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css inline only, and from my experience you need to do it with tables, since not all email services (none maybe) understand divs that well, I also recommend to stay within 600 px wide for the template, since its usually displayed in "panes" like yahoo mail, gmail, outlook etc. there's a lot of material you can check over at this page:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

there's no html, body or title declaration, just start with `<table></table>` like if was your body.

outlook 2007 will probably be the one with the most restraints.

good luck

Answer (score 2):

In css, you can use `font` or `font-family` to change the font. I don't see anything that would actually change the font in your code there!

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp

Comment: Hi Stack Overflow's code display method is very clumsy and it has eaten half of the html code I posted

Answer (score 1):

Don't send email in HTML.  It is much more likely to be flagged as spam if you do.